# Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: collection is not defined with publish/subscribe in place

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I read similar questions but could not find one with publish/subscribe to match.

The browser failed to see the collection contactsCol, why and how fo fix it? Thanks

```js
// imports/api/contacts.js
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';

export const ContactsCol = new Mongo.Collection('contactsCol');


///server/publication.js

import {ContactsCol}        from '../imports/api/contacts.js';

Meteor.publish('contactsCol', function () {
  if (!this.userId) return;
  if (this.userId && Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId}).profile.carsInfoMenu.indexOf('a') != -1){
    console.log('contactsCol retured documents');
    return ContactsCol.find();
  }
  return;
});


// client/main.js
Template.body.onCreated(function () {
   Meteor.subscribe('contactsCol');
});

Template.input.helpers({
  'listData': function (searchFor){
      return contactsCol.find().fetch();  //<<<< this line is causing the error
  }
});
```

**Update of what I tried for no avail:**

Added the following to main/client.js

```js
`import {contactsCol} from "../imports/api/contacts.js";

  Template.body.onCreated(function () {
  Meteor.subscribe('contactsCol');


Template.input.helpers({
  'listData': function (searchFor){  //17c
  return contactsCol.find().fetch();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the collection on the client as well. Right now it's an undefined variable.

```
// client/main.js
import { ContactsCol } from '../imports/api/contacts.js';
Template.body.onCreated(function () {
   Meteor.subscribe('contactsCol');
});

Template.input.helpers({
  'listData': function (searchFor){
      return ContactsCol.find().fetch();  //<<<< this line is causing the error
  }
});
```

The subscription only loads the data from the server to the client. The client still needs to define the collection to store those documents in and access them from. Importing the collection provides this

EDIT: Missed the capitalization of the module export

Comment: I already tried that among other things for no avail. I will update the question to reflect. Your solution gives the browser error: `Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

Comment: try the absolute import path `'/imports/api/contacts';` instead of relative maybe?

Comment: that did not work. please notice the "C" vs. "c" in the export vs. the subscription. why this problem is it expected to be fixed with import since the imported variable is not being used in the subscription?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the capitalization when I was copy/pasting. As I said in my answer, the subscription does not create a collection for you to use, it only loads data into that collection from the server. The collection on the client is created with `new Mongo.Collection`, and then you use that collection object to fetch and manipulate data

Comment: to clarify, the publication and subscription can be called anything and it won't change how you access the data

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I removed the subscription line from client/main.js

```js
Template.body.onCreated(function () {
  // Meteor.subscribe('contactsCol');
```

Added this import statement to the top of the file

```
import {ContactsCol} from "../imports/api/contacts.js";
```

And in the helper method I used:

```
return ContactsCol.find().fetch();
```

why is it working fine now with out subscription? I have no idea. would be great if some one can explain. thx

Comment: Do you have the `autopublish` package installed? Meteor projects start with `autopublish` for rapid prototyping, and it automatically sends all data from the server to the client for all collections